# Multiple wpostmeta.meta_key

Tags: wp-query, mysql, query-string

i need to add a new condition to this query:

```
       $querystr = "
       SELECT  DISTINCT meta_value  FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id IN(     
       SELECT DISTINCT wpostmeta.post_id
       FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
       WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
       AND wpostmeta.meta_key  = 'Sport' AND wpostmeta.meta_value  = Soccer' 
       AND wposts.post_type = 'post' ) AND meta_key ='event_name' 
       ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value ASC
```

I want to add something like, After check key "Sport" value "Soccer", the condition:

```
      AND wpostmeta.meta_key  = 'Event_ID' AND wpostmeta.meta_value  = '159'
```

Can you help me ? 
Thanks !

Comment: This kind of query is going to be very expensive, have you considered refactoring how you store data to be more performant? Custom taxonomies could provide **significant** performance improvements here and eliminate the need for raw SQL

Comment: Unfortunately on my server raw sql is more fast then wp query. Can you help me with this Sql query?

Comment: It's not that this is an SQL vs WP_Query thing, although WP_Query allows caching, it's that the post meta table wasn't designed for searches. It was designed for "fetch meta where post ID is known" not for searches across meta values. As a result, what you're trying to do can be hideously expensive/slow, SQL or not. This is why taxonomys were added with their own tables that have the performance characteristics your query requires. Without moving away from post meta this query will never be fast no matter how you write it